# Require rebase commands from gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

I want to know commands associated with gerrit rebase button to rebase the patch.
Our requirement "Rebase the patch and Submit"
As most of the time we are below error when we are submitting the patch:

Our Gerrit policy is set to "fast-forward" only (it cannot be changed).

## After submitting one patch successfully, i am getting the below error:

Project policy requires all submissions to be a fast-forward.

## Please rebase the change locally and upload again for review

With rebase button, i am able to do rebase.

Is there any command/script to automate this rebase process.

Comment: The Cherry-pick submit type is basically the same as rebasing immediately prior to submission (the only difference I can think of is the added metadata in the footer of the commit when cherry-picking), so please elaborate on why using that submit type isn't an option.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to automate it? Anyway If the change needs a rebase it means, that during the review another commit pushed to the main branch. So dont submit anything else if you have already a change on review. Or even dont push another change simultaneously. because if you have separate 2 changes on review - then second submitted should be rebased with the other one. and before push any code to review first check that is there any new commit on remote branch which should be rebased first locally.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create new Job and trigger it at the end of the Gerrit Job (the plugin with Gerrit).
2. The first job updated Gerrit +2 code review + 1 verify and trigger second job and pass all the parameters.
3. Now you can submit (if this is head or rebase if no).

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 10
echo $WORKSPACE
echo 'ssh -p 29418 gerrit-server gerrit review --project switch-dev --rebase'  $GERRIT_CHANGE_NUMBER,$GERRIT_PATCHSET_NUMBER
cd $WORKSPACE
if [ $GERRIT_PATCHSET_NUMBER -eq '1' ] ; then
    ssh -p 29418 gerrit-serve gerrit review --project switch-dev --submit  $GERRIT_CHANGE_NUMBER,$GERRIT_PATCHSET_NUMBER
    ssh -p 29418 gerrit-serve gerrit review --project switch-dev --rebase  $GERRIT_CHANGE_NUMBER,$GERRIT_PATCHSET_NUMBER
fi
if [ $GERRIT_PATCHSET_NUMBER -eq '2' ] ; then
    ssh -p 29418 gerrit-serve gerrit review --project switch-dev --submit  $GERRIT_CHANGE_NUMBER,$GERRIT_PATCHSET_NUMBER
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

You can write a python script for this. For this you need to first obtain change details then fetch current patchset then rebase and upload.

Steps :

1. get current patchset details using

   ```
    ssh -p <port number> <server_name >  gerrit query  --current-patch-set <change_number> --format=JSON
   ```

   parse it and get current_patchset_number and refs which will be used in step2 and step3.
2. Fetch change to local repo.

   If you check the cherry-pick command in gerrit , its same for all changes except the ref. You will get this ref from first step. Use that and cherry pick your CL to local repo.
3. Upload a new patchset

   ```
    git push origin HEAD:refs/changes/< current_patchset_number+1 >/< change_number >
   ```

Comment: I think you mean `HEAD:refs/changes/< change_number >`